# Printing variables within Underscore template ternary

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash, template-engine

Is it possible to print a variable in an underscore template during an evaluation like.

```
<a href="<%=data.active ? 'the/url' : 'another/url/<%='data.id'%>'%>">Link with printed parameter</a>
```

This gives me an Unexpected identifier error. I've tried with various excapings around the second `%>` but it just prints literally. I've also tried using the `print()` alias so that the compiler doesn't get confused by the repeating `%>`, however no luck. Is there a way to do this within a ternary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works without problems when you don't try do use nested the templates.

```js
var source = document.getElementById("testTemplate").innerHTML;
var testTemplate = _.template(source);

document.getElementById("target1").innerHTML = testTemplate({
  data: {
    active: false,
    id: 12345
  }
});

document.getElementById("target2").innerHTML = testTemplate({
  data: {
    active: true,
    id: 67890
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="testTemplate">
  <a href="<%= data.active ? 'the/url' : 'another/url/' + encodeURIComponent(data.id) %>">Link with printed parameter</a>
  <p>The URL is "<%= data.active ? 'the/url' : 'another/url/' + encodeURIComponent(data.id) %>".</p>
  <hr>
</script>

<div id="target1"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>
```

Note: Even if your `data.id` normally is strictly numeric, it's better to just use `encodeURIComponent` anyway when you are building a URL. Escaping data cleanly is a good habit to get into.